# change navigation bar title's color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know how to change the color of my navigation bar title but when I write this code:

```
UILabel * label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] autorelease];
label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
label.text=@"Title"; //CUSTOM TITLE
[label sizeToFit];
```

I want my navigation bar to show the cell's title, not custom title.

Here is my table view code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ghazalList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier"; 

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease]; 
    } 

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [ghazalList objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the navigation bar's title to change when a cell is selected?

Comment: NO .  when i want change title color and write the this code label.text=@"Title"; this code changed my cell selected title  .. i want only change  the color not title

Comment: If you don't want the custom title, then don't write `label.text=@"Title"; //CUSTOM TITLE` ?? I think I'm not understanding you correctly...

Comment: OK LOOK suppose , we have table view and 5 cells each cell has a specific title Cell 1 / Cell 2 / Cell 3 and so on ... now i want change the color of my navigation bar on the AnotherViewController not RootViewController .. so when i use that code my title changed to @"TITLE"  .
for example when i select CELL 2 / my AnotherView Controller's title became CELL 2 . how can change title color with out change the title of cell ? 
when i write this code :label.text=@"Title"; my anotherviewController's title changed to TILTE . i don't  want change my title according the cell label . JUST THE COLOR .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adam :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (!anotherViewController) {
    anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    anotherViewController.navigationItem.title=[ghazalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController loadGhazal:indexPath.row];

}else {
    [anotherViewController loadGhazal:indexPath.row];
    anotherViewController.navigationItem.title=[ghazalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];  
}
```

}

i creat a poem application so , i have 495 cell and 495  HTML file [poems] . each cell [POEM 1 to 495] has a special pooem . everything works fine but , this damn title color drive me crazy ... i put your code the color had changed but the title changed to Poem 5 !

Comment: OK so it seems that you're pushing another controller to the navigation controller, and are setting the title of its navigation item. Try experimenting with the line `label.text = self.navigationItem.title;` so that you set the title based on the `anotherViewController.navigationItem.title`, not `self` (I didn't know what `self` was in the code in your question, I don't know what method it is in, in which class)

Comment: i tried with this line anotherViewController.navigationItem.title
but i got the error that undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: Adam plz help me my application has been finished i am just waiting for this !

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation, try

```
UILabel * label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] autorelease];
label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
label.text = self.navigationItem.title;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: thank you adam , it works :D but still has a little bit problem 
if i select any cell the title is Cell 5 ! why ? 
if i select cell 46 the title is Cell 5 or any number !

Comment: Do you implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in `UITableViewDelegate`? What does it do?